# WARNING! Error adding current blueprint templates as alternative for JHipster templates

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to make a JHipster blueprint. Whenever I try to generate a project with it, I have warnings like

```
DEBUG! Found blueprint generator-jhipster-QuestionURL and server with namespace jhipster-QuestionURL:server
WARNING! Error adding current blueprint templates as alternative for JHipster templates.
Error: The Namespace jhipster-QuestionURL:server may not be correct. Please check your configuration and ensure your blueprint folder start with "generator-". Detail: Error: Error parsing namespace jhipster-QuestionURL:server
    at module.exports.jhipsterTemplatePath (/home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster-QuestionURL2/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:187:13)
    at new JHipsterBaseBlueprintGenerator (/home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster-QuestionURL2/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:68:49)
    at new JHipsterServerGenerator (/home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster-QuestionURL2/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/server/index.js:75:5)
    at new module.exports (/home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster-QuestionURL2/generators/server/index.js:9:9)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:801:23)
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:773:17)
    at JHipsterServerGenerator.composeWith (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1326:42)
    at JHipsterServerGenerator._composeBlueprint (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:516:43)
    at async JHipsterServerGenerator.composeWithBlueprints (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:413:34)
    at async JHipsterServerGenerator._postConstruct (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/server/index.js:96:7)
     info Using blueprint generator-jhipster-QuestionURL for server subgenerator
```

showing up for each sub-generators I'm overriding. These warnings don't interrupt the questions asked by JHipster, but it prevents JHipster to generate the project in the end. When I finish answering all questions, I have this error message

```
ERROR! Template file src/main/docker/jib/entrypoint.sh was not found at /home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster-QuestionURL2/generators/server/templates
Error: Template file src/main/docker/jib/entrypoint.sh was not found at /home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster-QuestionURL2/generators/server/templates
    at /home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster-QuestionURL2/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:2307:25
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster-QuestionURL2/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:2237:42
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster-QuestionURL2/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:2234:29
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports.writeFilesToDisk (/home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster-QuestionURL2/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:2233:45)
    at module.exports.writeFiles (/home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster-QuestionURL2/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/server/files.js:1929:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dev/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1097:23)
    at /home/dev/node_modules/run-async/index.js:49:25
```

I am not familiar with namespaces so I can't pinpoint the problem. Does anyone know what is causing this and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you share the command line that you use to run the blueprint with jhipster?

Comment: Yes, it was "jhipster -d --blueprints QuestionURL", which is the command that was given in the README

Comment: Did you link your blueprint to global? To do thar go to your blueprint folder`cd generator-jhipster-my-blueprint` than `npm link`

Comment: Yes I did, as you can see from the first error message, my blueprint is found